# Why smash doesn't suppress the horizontal space of subscript with sum?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, boxes, subscripts, mathtools

I try to understand the smash command, and I made a simple example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \sum_{\mathclap{\text{LOOOOONG}}}f(x) 
 \qquad \sum_{\smash{\text{LOOOOONG}}}f(x) 
 \qquad \sum_{\text{LOOOOONG}}f(x) 
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

But, using smash seems to actually do nothing about the horizontal spacing. I don't understand why this happens (my first source to understand smash and mathclap is [macros, A complement to \smash, \llap, and \rlap](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf).

Why isn't the result of the smash more like the mathclap case?

[image: Three ways to deals with long subscript in sum]

Comment: `\smash` only affects vertical space

Comment: \smash is about the vertical dimension.

Comment: Oh...! This makes more sense. Thanks a lot. Should I delete my question or keep ip?

Comment: don't edit answers in to the question, it makes the question/answer format hard to follow

Answer (score 2):

`\smash` only affects vertical space, it produces a box with zero height and depth but the natural width of the argument